# Why people feel more sleepy while doing something that's not interesting even when they are not actually tired?

Tags: sleep

We often see people and students yawning while reading a boring course book. But, when told about something interesting, their sleepiness vanishes.
Why and how does this happen? What are the exact hormones or biochemical pathways involved?
[NOTE: This is seen more when the temperature is slightly below body temperature at around 20-18°C. How does temperature play a role in facilitating this process?]
Thanks